# 404 (Page Not Found) Image Nominations

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

I noticed this was missing here, so...

**What should the 404 image be for this site?**

Should it be funny like the other ones or more serious?

Please post only one image with source per answer for voting/rights.

Related:
["Amusing 404 "Page Not Found" Images for Trilogy sites?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/27121#27121) on Stack Overflow Meta

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to guess we might not have the bandwidth for a little Flash or HTML5 game.

But we really should have a little Flash or HTML5 game. How awesome would that be?

Comment: The "sketchy-404.png" we have now is a bit larger than 32KB.

http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/sinuous/01/
is about a third of that, so games should be possible with proper compression.

Comment: I love the idea of a game for 404 (and upvoted it) - but how widespread is HTML5? And Flash may or may not be available/turned on (iPads don't have it, and I turn it off unless there's a specific reason to have it on). We'd still need a fallback image.

Comment: +1 for HTML (it doesn't have to be 5, please reduce the buzzword usage), maybe something like Google's Pac-man game; NOT a Flash game!!

Comment: Canvas is supported by newer versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. Explorer Canvas (JavaScript) adds support for IE but is 12KB in the compiled version. We can use jQuery, so the fallback can be a single replaceWith or a $().ajax([...]) for exCanvas.
It should have a title screen, so it doesn't affect performance by default.

Comment: This is a cool idea but should encapsulate the notion of "NOT FOUND." Like a game where you have to dig for treasure, but the treasure simply isn't there.

Answer (score 10):

```
404 - Page not found

It is pitch black. You are likely to be eaten by a grue.

> HELP

The page you wanted wasn't where you thought it was, and now you're lost.

You can:
 * Try searching for it
 * Browse recent questions
 * Browse popular tags
```

...or some variation on the above.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Error 404: Island Not Found]

You control one of three different vessels lost at sea.

Link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5013896/404Game/404game.htm

There is still room for optimizations, but most features are ready.
The title screen definitely is not.

Answer (score -4):

There are some copyright issues but it probably wont cost to much to get the [Mario saves the princess](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPXmNfFEarw) from Seth Macfarlane or some similar prank :)